# SharePoint Server Search returning documents for a specific client id

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'd like to use the SharePoint Server search and return documents for a specific client id.

The code now returns everything with a wildcard search:

```
  using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(hostWeb))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(hostWebAdmin, hostWebPassword, hostWebDomain);


            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
            var scope = "All Sites";
            keywordQuery.QueryText = String.Format("{0} AND Path:\"{1}\" AND Scope:\"{2}\" AND IsDocument:1", searchValue, hostWeb+"PropertyDocuments", scope);

            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            //foreach (SearchResults s in searchResults)
            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
            {
```

looking at the results of the resultRow - i cannot find a key for client id or client name.
Any suggestions on how to filter by the client id?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get additional fields for you to filter on in your results, you need to take a few steps. First, make sure you have a managed property that is mapped to the crawled property that has your ID and is marked as 'Retrievable' and 'Queryable'. If you don't know how to do that, follow this link [Manage the Search Schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667%28v=office.15%29.aspx). You will have to run a full crawl after updating or adding new managed properties. You can use the managed property directly in your query, but to get it actually returned in your results you need to add it as an additional field to be returned. For example, say your managed property is named *ClientID*.

```
int clientId = 5;
keywordQuery.QueryText = String.Format("{0} AND Path:\"{1}\" AND Scope:\"{2}\" AND ClientID:\"{3}\" AND IsDocument:1", searchValue, hostWeb+"PropertyDocuments", scope, clientId);
keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("ClientID");
```

You can add multiple fields this way to return in your results for additional filtering or display purposes.